# JPA - Delete entities from @ManyToMany self

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

I have documents, that are referenced by other documents. I store this connection in the entity.

```
@Entity
public class Document extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "DREF", joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCID", referencedColumnName="ID"), inverseJoinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "REFBYDOCID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Document> referencedBy = new HashSet<Document>();

}
```

But I have problems when I try to delete.

For example: When Doc1 is referenced by Doc2, then I can't delete Doc2.

For that I have to remove Doc2 from the other Documents referencedBy Sets. But I can't get the reference of these Documents from Doc2.

1) I tried to write a method to get the references, but I couldn't done it.

```
public synchronized Document getReferencedDocuments(Integer Id) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Document> cq = cb.createQuery(Document.class);
        Root<Document> e = cq.from(Document.class);
        ????
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        return q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

2) I have tried to store the referenced documents too, but it was a dead end.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the inverse side of the association:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "referencedBy")
private Set<Document> referencedDocuments = new HashSet<>();
```

Or you could write a query to find all the documents referencing the document to delete:

```
select doc1 from Document doc1
join doc1.referencedBy doc2 
where doc2.id = :doc2Id
```

You should avoid using the criteria API if you don't need to construct a dynamic query based on multiple... criteria. JPQL is much easier to write, read and understand.